# Can we define a set of DSL operation in Scala that perform parallelly with each other just like using pipe-line processing in Linux

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

Forgive me my poor English but I will try my best to express my question.

Suppose I want to process a large text whose operation is to filter content through a key word; change them to lowercase; and then print them onto the standard output. As we all know, we can do this using pipeline in Linux BASH script :

```
cat article.txt | grep "I" | tr "I" "i" > /dev/stdout
```

where `cat article.txt`, `grep "I"`, `tr "I" "i" > /dev/stdout` are running in parallel.

In Scala, we probably do it like this:

```
//or read from a text file , e.g. article.txt 
val strList = List("I", "am", "a" , "student", ".", "I", "come", "from", "China", ".","I","love","peace")  
strList.filter( _ == "I").map(_.toLowerCase).foreach(println)
```

My question is how we can make `filter`, `map` and `foreach` parallel?

thx

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. The bash script isn't running in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.9, parallel collections were added. To parallelize the loop, all you have to do is to convert it by calling the `par` member function.

Your code would look like this:

```
val strList = List("I", "am", "a" , "student", ".", "I", "come", "from", "China", ".","I","love","peace")  // or read from a text file , e.g. article.txt 
strList.par.filter( _ == "I").map(_.toLowerCase).foreach(println)
```

Comment: `par` just change the collection to parallel type. Though each function of collection is parallel but not with each other when group together. Say, `strList.par` make strList parallelable, but  `filter`, `map` and `foreach` are called one by one, only parallel operation happens in each function

Comment: That is, `map` won't be performed until `filter` finishes in your example. What I want is that `filter`, `map` and `foreach` is running parallely, not one by one, just like pipeline in linux

Comment: To clarify, do you want data to flow from each operation as it becomes available? So cat is streaming into the grep which streams out to tr etc. If so, wouldn't it be more efficient to compose a single function that filters/maps the original collection?

Comment: thx, I wonder whether we can define a set of DSL to get similar to Linux pipeline effect

Answer (score 2):

If you change your List to an Iterator you'll see that the filter/map/foreach are not grouped anymore.

Try this:

```
val strList = Iterator("I", "am", "a" , "student", ".", "I", "come", "from", "China", ".","I","love","peace")  
strList.filter{ s => println("f"); s == "I"}.map{s => println("m"); s.toLowerCase}.foreach{s =>println("p")}
```

You'll see :
f
m
p
f
f
f
f
f
m
p
f
f
f
f
f
m
p
f
f

Instead of: 
f
f
f
f
f
f
f
f
f
f
f
f
f
m
m
m
p
p
p

Because when you apply a transformation to a List, it immediatly returns a new List. But when applying a transformation to an Iterator, it will only run when you traverse it (with the `foreach` in this case).

Comment: However, this is not a parallel execution of filter and map.  Both are still executed by the same thread.

Comment: @Stefan, indeed, but by his comment on tstenner's answer I think this may be the behavior he's looking for, not necessarily multi-threaded execution.

Comment: thx, That is the behavior that I'm looking for, but would be better if it becomes multi-threaded execution

Answer (score 2):

tstenner's solution is probably the most efficiency solution in your situation, since it can achieve a high degree of parallelism (each single item could be theoretically processed in parallel).  However, your bash example is just using pipeline parallelism and this kind of parallelism is unfortunately not directly supported by Scalas parallel collections.

To achieve pipeline parallelism your operators (filter, map, foreach) have to be executed by different threads, e.g., by using Actors.

In general I think it would be nice feature for Scala to have a simple API for that.  But, for your example I doubt that pipeline parallelism would speedup your execution time that much.  If you just use very simple filter and map operations I assume that the communication overhead (for FIFOs / Actor mailboxes) consumes the whole speedup of your parallel execution.

Comment: Should we advise Scala development team to provide such pipeline parallelism api in future , e.g. 2.11 version

Comment: Would be definitely useful, yes.  But it is also not that hard to implement.  I implemented it for my research project (a mashup framework) with operators like map, flatMap, filter, groupBy, and reduce.  In case that I'm allowed to release the code open source (most probably not before April) I will leave another comment.

Comment: The answer doesn't really make sense. There are no parallel computations in the bash script at all. Considering that you read from a file and the processing is more than trivial, I don't see any reason or benefit in making it parallel (which is very easily done by adding `.par`).

Comment: Read the bash manual if you doubt that different processes in a bash pipe are executed in parallel.  Of course they are, though the benefit may be small if you mix expensive operations with cheap ones.  However, the original question is of general nature and not regarding simple file read operations.  That's why it requires a general answer.  For longer pipelines consisting of several expensive operations it definitely does make sense to run these operations in parallel.  And `.par` uses data parallelism instead of pipeline parallelism.  Thus it does not answer the user's question.

Answer (score 2):

Use a view:

```
val strList = List("I", "am", "a" , "student", ".", "I", "come", "from", "China", ".","I","love","peace")  // or read from a text file , e.g. article.txt 
strList.view.filter( _ == "I").map(_.toLowerCase).foreach(println)
```

Views store the operations on collections (`filter` and `map` in this case) and execute them only when you request elements from them (`foreach` in this case). So first it would apply filter and map to "I", then to "am", and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for a single argument from your chain of functions. Then apply this function to a parallel collection. Note that the `println` will not be called in order of the original collection.

```
def fmp(xs: Seq[String]){
  xs.par.foreach{x => 
    for(
      kw <- Option(x).filter(_ == "I"); 
      lc <- kw.map(_.toLowerCase)
    ) println(lc)
  }
}
```